# Prevent Lenovo recovery from wiping out personal data

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, thinkpad, recovery-disk

I have a Lenovo T430s with a C and a Q partition. C is for system and Q is for recovery.

My plan is to create a D partition with Windows disk management tool  where I can save my personal data and then restore the system with the recovery DVDs. My question is, will the recovery mechanism wipe out the D partition also?

Unfortunately, the manual does not address this special case. It says:

> During the recovery process, all data on the hard disk drive will be
>   deleted. Copy any important data or personal files that you want to
>   keep onto removable media or a network drive before you start the
>   recovery process.
>
> If your computer has multiple internal hard disk drives installed, a
>   window is displayed, asking if you would like to format all the
>   internal hard disk drives. Select one of the following as you desire:
>
> - Click Yes if you want to delete all data on the hard disk drives.
> - Click No if you want to format the system drive only.

I think this basically means it will delete all my partitions if I have one hard drive, but it isn't clear whether this applies to partitions.

[source](http://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/options/win8_method1_en.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I tried it and it turned out it **deletes all the partitions** then creates its own.

Answer (score 1):

It WILL delete your partitions.

The recovery system is a sort of destroy and recreate the disk state, thus wiping other made partitions. This may be useful for some people who don't properly know how to handle partitions (a flawed installation of linux, for instance).

I would recommend you use third party cloning tools, such as clonezilla, and create partition images (which you can later on restore).